# Plotting a time series graph Error with Ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have the following dataset

```
# A tibble: 11 x 3
  Anio  Porc_PBI
 <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
 1  2008 BPS       6.42
 2  2009 BPS       6.52
 3  2010 BPS       6.98
 4  2011 BPS       6.93
 5  2012 BPS       7.88
 6  2013 BPS       7.93
 7  2014 BPS       7.97
 8  2015 BPS       8.26
 9  2016 BPS       8.43
 10 2017 BPS       8.83
 11 2018 BPS       9.05
```

And i want to plot a time series graph showing the temporal evolution of the Porc_PBI variable. Hence, i want to have an x axis with the Anio variable and an y axis variable with the Porc_PBI variable. I tried using the following code:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Anio, y=Porc_PBI)) +
 geom_line(color="red", size=2, linetype="dotted")+
 geom_point(color="blue", size=3)  +
 xlab("Año") +
 ylab("Porcentaje del PBI (%)")+
 scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(2008,2018, by=1),
               labels=seq(2008,2018, by=1)
 )
```

With the following result:

[image: Time series graph]

How can i fix the x-axis labels and show all the years from 2008 to 2018 on it?

Thanks

Comment: Use `scale_x_continuous` instead of `scale_x_discrete` because your year values are numerical (double)

Answer (score 3):

Use  `scale_x_continuous` instead of `scale_x_discrete`:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Anio, y = Porc_PBI)) +
  geom_line(color="red", size=2, linetype="dotted")+
  geom_point(color="blue", size=3)  +
  xlab("Año") +
  ylab("Porcentaje del PBI (%)") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2008, 2018, by = 1))
```

[image]